# Leaving hops out freezer for an hour

Tags: hops, hop-utilization

I have doubt with a friend. Right now, when we brew we get the hops from the freezer, weight and add to the boiling wort **at the same moment** that they are needed.

I was thinking if it's OK to weight **all** the hops just before the wort boils and leave them in tuppers in the same room as where we're brewing (which at this point it's hot & humid).

My friend says that it's not good for the hops and prefers to do it at the moment. I think it doesn't affect in any noticeable way and prefer doing the batch.

So, the question: will my way affect the hops in a noticeable way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you won't notice a difference.

While alpha acids and precious volitiles fade with age and air exposure. You won't register any difference with the limited time you're talking about. I would wrap them in foil or use a zip lock, to prevent contamination that may not get sterilized (whirlpool additions), and at least refrigerate.

Photo from Coachella Valley Brewing Co. Preparing for a brew of their signature IPA , Monumentous. All weighed out and waiting in the walk in cooler.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! We're doing the batch and then we put in the freezer until it's time.